# How do I pass my iOS app name as a traffic source when it is playing embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I have an iOS app in which I play YouTube videos using the YouTube iframe API.

Inside YouTube, when looking in the analytics panel->Traffic sources
I'm seeing the hits classified as "Other YouTube features"->"Unknown"

Is there a parameter I can pass that would identify the hits as coming from my app?

I can see that most apps playing YouTube videos are registered under "External" and then the name of the app (E.g. WhatsApp, embedly.com etc.)

I'm using the UIWebView to load an HTML that's using the YouTube iframe API
like this:

```
<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%%' height=100%%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/<videoId>enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the the analytics are using the [`origin`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#origin) parameter of the iFrame API.

You might be able to get analytics information by adding `&origin=http://com.example.yourApp` or some other valid URL to your player parameters.

Autoplay seems to work for me like so:

```
<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%%' height=100%%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/jCHE0Tjw6MA?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1&origin=http://com.example.yourApp' frameborder='0'>
```

Swift implementation:

```
let webView = UIWebView(...)
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

let videoID = "zN-GGeNPQEg"

let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&origin='http://com.example.myApp/'' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Do you have an idea why the origin param cancels the autoplay ? I'm passing enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=1 and it autoplays but when im adding the origin it stops autoplaying.

Comment: @BoazSaragossi edited my answer to include an iFrame with `origin` that autoplays for me.

Comment: @BoazSaragossi added an example in Swift where adding `origin` doesn't break autoplay in a `UIWebView`.

Comment: @BoazSaragossi did my update help you?  Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Yes it works now! the ' ' around the origin value is what i forgot. Thank you!